# Setting HTML input of type time prints invalid input time

Tags: javascript, input, time

In this simple html
`<input type="time" id="tm" name="tm">`, I try to set the time using `document.getElementById('tm').valueAsDate = new Date();`, but the time is set to "23:45:04.123", which results in an error in the input. I get a tooltip "Please select a valid value...."

I tried this in Firefox 94.0.2 and Edge 96.0.1054.34 - the same result. I'm using a German Windows 10 x64, if that matters.

Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tg0v43m9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment

```js
var now = new Date(Date.now());
document.getElementById('tm').valueAsDate = moment(now, ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
```

Also check these options.

```
var now = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: true,
}));
document.getElementById('tm').valueAsDate = now;
```

Comment: moment was not defined. Might by some library. But the "toLocaleString" did indeed work.

Comment: @KungPhoo  I forgot to mention. Yes, it's a library.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<input type="time" id="tm" name="tm">
<script>

    var today = new Date();

    var time =today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes() ;
    document.getElementById("tm").value = time;

</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, specially what you change and why this should fix the issue ?

Comment: simply i create a new date and then get hours & minutes using getHours() and getMinutes() after that assign the value to input.

Comment: Can you include it in your answer thanks to [edit] ? :)

Comment: I Included already - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70132819/17343411

Comment: I mean the explaination. To make people easier understand your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the [hours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) & [minutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes) part separately and join them together to achieve your desired format.

```js
var now = new Date(Date.now());

// Getting Hours from the time
var hours = now.getHours();

// Getting minutes from the time
var minutes = "0" + now.getMinutes();

// Displaying time in H:M format
var time = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
  
document.getElementById('tm').value = time; 
// document.getElementById('tm').value = "23:45"; // works
```

```html
<input type="time" id="tm" name="tm">
```